# Insert into string based on Regex Match Index

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to insert a new line before each one of my regex matches. Currently i'm getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I realize that the index needs to be offset for all the new line characters i'm inserting (4 chars in total).

Do you guys know any way around this?

Thanks!

```
string origFileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);

string cleanFileContents = origFileContents.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");

Regex regex = new Regex(@"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9a-zA-Z]*--)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(cleanFileContents);

int counter = 0;

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    cleanFileContents.Insert(match.Index + 4 * counter, Environment.NewLine);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you multiply 4 with `counter`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Perhaps he is trying to compensate for the string getting longer? In which case it should be `Environment.NewLine.Length * counter`?

Comment: Environment.newline inserts \r\n, which is 4 characters. I figured that match.index is based on the old length of the string and because i'm inserting 4 chars in every iteration i need to compensate for that. No?

Comment: @bjoern - `"\r\n"` is two characters (perhaps you are thinking of bytes?)

Comment: Just FYI, that [`Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Singleline) option isn't doing anything useful.  All it does is change the behavior of the dot metacharacter (`.`), and there are no dots in your regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
cleanFileContents = regex.Replace(
    cleanFileContents,
    Environment.NewLine + "$0");
```

That said, your problem may be that Environment.NewLine.Length is probably 2, not 4. Edit: also, as Cyborg has pointed out, Insert doesn't modify the string in place, but returns a new one.

By the way, if you're trying to match literal brackets, you'll need to escape them.

Comment: +1 - This is much simpler. I didn't look at it closely enough the first time round or I wouldn't have bothered posting my answer.

Comment: I ended up implementing this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see at least these identifiable issues with this code.

1. `"\r\n"` is two characters, not 4. You should use `Environment.NewLine.Length * counter`.
2. `cleanFileContents.Insert(...)` returns a new string, it does not modify 'cleanFileContents'. You need something like `cleanFileContents = cleanFileContents.Insert(...)`

Suggested edits:

```
string origFileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);

// Changed cleanFileContents to a StringBuilder for performance reasons
var cleanFileContents = New StringBuilder( origFileContents.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "") );

Regex regex = new Regex(@"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9a-zA-Z]*--)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(cleanFileContents.ToString());

int counter = 0;

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    cleanFileContents.Insert(match.Index + Environment.NewLine.Length * counter, Environment.NewLine);
    counter++;
}

var result = cleanFileContents.ToString()
```

Comment: thanks! I needed to use match.Index + Environment.NewLine.Length * counter since the slashes don't add to the length. Did not know that. #3, you are correct, rookie mistake. #4 the match index is the index of the first character of the match. I want to insert a new line before the match.

Comment: @bjoern - Already heavily updated my "list". Everything was fine except for the magnitude of your multiplication and `Insert` returning a new string.

Comment: @bjoern - I also recommend you use a StringBuilder. It's much better performance-wise (and the [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tyt41s0.aspx) function is more intuitive).

Comment: It may yield the correct result, but it's far from fine.  Have you tried [Rawling's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14632642/20938)?  Because it looks to me like you're reinventing [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx).

Comment: @AlanMoore - That's true. I hadn't thought of that - Rawling's answer is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow the logic on
match.Index + 4 * counter
you do know * is applied before + ?

Similar to Cyborgx37 - it was not posted when I started this
ReadAllLines to split on line feeds might be faster

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9a-zA-Z]*--)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
StringBuilder sbAll = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbLine = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path"))
{
    sbLine.Append(line);
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(line);

    int counter = 0;

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        sbLine.Insert(match.Index + Environment.NewLine.Length * counter, Environment.NewLine);
        counter++;
    }
    sbAll.Append(line);
    sbLine.Clear();
}
```

Comment: +1 for identifying the index math issue, but there's another subtle bug you are not addressing - as text is inserted into the 'cleanFileContents' string, the string grows longer. Meaning that the match indeces and the string will no longer by in sync. They should be inserted in reverse order to overcome this issue.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I did not address that subtle bug as I don't think insert is the correct approach.

Comment: The multiplication and addition are happening fine, it's just that the multiplier is wrong. Your StringBuilder solution is nothing like what OP is trying to achieve, unless there's nothing but matches in the input.

Comment: Well, Environment.newline inserts \r\n, which is 4 characters. I figured that match.index is based on the old length of the string and because i'm inserting 4 chars in every iteration i need to compensate for that. No?

Comment: @Rawling I agree I missed big time on that

Comment: @bjoern the slashes don't add to the length of the string.

Comment: Oops... the multiplication was intentional and the thinking correct (though the magnitude was incorrect).

Comment: I needed to use Environment.newline.length since the slashes don't count. Thanks guys!